# Parallel::ForkManager takes too much time to start 'finish' function

Tags: perl, parallel-processing

I use the regular Parallel::ForkManager module in Perl. I execute around 10 children processes. 'passes_thresholds' function takes few milliseconds or nanoseconds (checked it). In case I run all processes one by one (without Parallel::ForkManager) the whole process took 80-250 milliseconds. In case I run them as parallel, the whole process takes at least 1 second. I found that the Fork spends 1 second to start the 'finish' function. I put a timer when the child process finished his job and should go to 'finish'- function. One second is too much for my development.

```
sub parallel_execute {
    my $this = shift;
    foreach my $a (@a_array) {
        my $pid = $this->{fork_manager}->start and next;
        my $res = $a->passes_thresholds();
        $a->{timer} = Benchmark::Timer->new();
        $svc->{timer}->start;
        $this->{fork_manager}->finish(0,{a => $a, plugin_result => $res});
    }
}

$this->{fork_manager}->run_on_finish( sub {
    my ($pid, $exit_code, $ident, $exit_signal, $core_dump, $data_structure_reference) = @_;
    my $a = $data_structure_reference->{a};
    if (exists $a->{timer}) {
        $a->{timer}->stop;
        debug "took: " . $a->{timer}->report;
    }
});
```

Do you have any idea why it took at least 1 second to start the 'finish' command?

(I am using Unix server, and perl 5.10)

Comment: The usual approach is to give each forked child more work to do, by sending each child a batch of items to work on instead of launching a child for every work item

Comment: Please add full source code. Probably `run_on_finish` does not get executed before all 10 processes are spawned.

Comment: Cross-posted to https://perlmonks.org/?node_id=1224835

Comment: That's much too quick, and you apparently have all these classes involved there.  What do you mean by "nanoseconds" -- do you expect methods to be called on objects, fork processes, and complete in nanoseconds? Then, what does the method lookup have to do in your class?  That may take a little time. Are objects being destroyed on `finish`? That may well take time.  (Probably unrelated, but why do you construct the timer object in the loop? Specially if you are counting milliseconds.)  Now, a whole second is indeed a lot but we need to see all relevant code.

Comment: From what I see your timer shows how long it took to complete the callback, not up to calling `finish`.  Now, `run_on_finish` uses files to transfer data and that's yet another wild card here, and _that_ can take time.

Comment: @Corion, Search engines link to www.perlmonks.org, so it's a better target than perlmonks.org (which requires a separate login).

Comment: Thank you all!!!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks you all, i found the problem. ForManager module has 'waitpid_blocking_sleep' parameter, which defined as 1 second by default. There is a function called 'set_waitpid_blocking_sleep' which we can defined this parameter (sleep time). We can set zero or fraction of seconds. I set this paramter to zero and it fixed my issue.

Comment: But please be careful with setting it to _zero_ as that changes how `P::FM` waits for children; review carefully ["Blocking Calls" in docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager#BLOCKING-CALLS). Note that you can use fractional sleeps via `Time::HiRes`.

Comment: I believe what I provided is much safer.

Comment: Note that @ikegami 's child handler by-passes the issue of waiting altogether (as far as I can tell), since  children get reaped as soon as they're done; and it is better not to muck about with those constants. It is also a general optimization I think, as _each_ child gets reaped once it's done (not the case with `wait_all_children`).

Answer (score 1):

The `on_finish` callback is only called when P::FM reaps a child, and P::FM only reaps a child under three conditions:

- When `$pm->start` is called and the number of children that have been started but not reaped is equal to the maximum.
- When `$pm->reap_finished_children` is called.
- When `$pm->wait_all_children` is called.

There could be an arbitrarily long delay between a child exiting and one the above events. Adding the following to your program should eliminate that delay:

```
$SIG{CHLD} = sub { $pm->reap_finished_children };
```

---

By the way, if the work performed by your child only takes "a few milliseconds or nanoseconds", you are actually slowing things down by using P::FM. Data passed to `finish` gets serialized and written to disk, then read from the disk and deserialized for the `on_finish` callback!

Comment: Thanks! can you please explain this command: $SIG{CHLD} = sub { $pm->reap_finished_children }; what is the goal for it?

Comment: It causes the sub to be called when the process receives the `CHLD` signal, which the OS sends when a child exits.